# provide an answer which is a documentsnapshot from firebase docs and play it with justaudio?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, navigation, provider

my app has 4 main page. i navigate trought those pages like this so i wont lose their state , is this the best way to do it ?

```
class mainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const mainPage({super.key});

  @override
  _mainPageState createState() => _mainPageState();
}

class _mainPageState extends State<mainPage> {
  static const double _playerminheight = 60.0;
  final _screens = [
    const home(),
    const Search(),
    const Saved(),
    const Settingss()
  ];
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
          children: _screens
              .asMap()
              .map((i, screen) => MapEntry(
                  i,
                  Offstage(
                    offstage: _currentIndex != i,
                    child: screen,
                  )))
              .values
              .toList()),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          iconSize: 28,
          selectedFontSize: 0,
          unselectedFontSize: 0,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(12, 16, 21, 1),
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: (i) => setState(() {
                _currentIndex = i;
              }),
          selectedItemColor: itemSelec,
          unselectedItemColor: itemUnselec,
          elevation: 4,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
                label: '',
                activeIcon: Icon(Icons.home)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline),
                label: '',
                activeIcon: Icon(Icons.play_circle)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined),
                label: '',
                activeIcon: Icon(Icons.favorite)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings_outlined),
                label: '',
                activeIcon: Icon(Icons.settings)),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

The home page displays a list of audiobooks when you click on one of them you navigate to a page where details of the audiobook are displayed from a fire store doc. but i want to navigate to that page without hiding my bottom navigation bar. is there another way so i wont hide my bottom navigation bar ? like instagram

```
Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => AudioPage(
                                                  snap: documentSnapshot,
                                                  id: documentSnapshot.id,
                                                )));
```

bellow the page I have a play button that is supposed to take the user to the second main page of my navigation bottom bar called audio player page. There I want to catch the id of the audiobook I clicked on and store the information like on the doc. And create the player with just audio package. What is the best way to achieve that ?

```
class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  const Search({super.key});

  @override
  State<Search> createState() => _searchState();
}

class _searchState extends State<Search> {
  late AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;
  final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: []);
  Stream<PositionData> get _positionDataStream =>
      Rx.combineLatest3<Duration, Duration, Duration?, PositionData>(
          _audioPlayer.positionStream,
          _audioPlayer.bufferedPositionStream,
          _audioPlayer.durationStream,
          (position, bufferedPosition, duration) => PositionData(
              position, bufferedPosition, duration ?? Duration.zero));
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()
      ..setUrl(
          'any url so it wont say that i didnt initialize my audioplayer');
  }

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final audiobookProvider =
        Provider.of<AudiobookProvider>(context).selectedAudiobookId;
    late Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> audiobook =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Audios')
            .doc(audiobookProvider)
            .snapshots();
    print(audiobookProvider);

    if (audiobookProvider != '') {
      return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: background,
          appBar: AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 80,
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(12, 16, 21, 1),
            bottomOpacity: 0.0,
            elevation: 0.0,
            centerTitle: true,
            scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
            leadingWidth: 70,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded,
                size: 28,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                print(audiobookProvider);
              },
            ),
            title: Text(
              nowplaying,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: textColors,
                  fontSize: titleS,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: audiobook,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
              DocumentSnapshot dbData = snapshot.data!;
              String url = dbData['Chapters'][0];
              _audioPlayer = (AudioPlayer()..setUrl(dbData['Chapters'][0]));
              return Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 60, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          StreamBuilder<PositionData>(
                              stream: _positionDataStream,
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                final positionData = snapshot.data;
                                return ProgressBar(
                                  baseBarColor: searchbar2,
                                  bufferedBarColor: searchbar2,
                                  progressBarColor: textColors,
                                  thumbColor: textColors,
                                  barHeight: 4,
                                  thumbRadius: 5,
                                  timeLabelLocation: TimeLabelLocation.below,
                                  timeLabelPadding: 3,
                                  timeLabelType: TimeLabelType.remainingTime,
                                  progress:
                                      positionData?.position ?? Duration.zero,
                                  buffered: positionData?.bufferedPosition ??
                                      Duration.zero,
                                  total:
                                      positionData?.duration ?? Duration.zero,
                                  onSeek: _audioPlayer.seek,
                                );
                              }),
                          Controls(audioplayer: _audioPlayer),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ));
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: background,
          appBar: AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 80,
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(12, 16, 21, 1),
            bottomOpacity: 0.0,
            elevation: 0.0,
            centerTitle: true,
            scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
            leadingWidth: 70,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded,
                size: 28,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                print(audiobookProvider);
              },
            ),
            title: Text(
              nowplaying,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: textColors,
                  fontSize: titleS,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      StreamBuilder<PositionData>(
                          stream: _positionDataStream,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            final positionData = snapshot.data;
                            return ProgressBar(
                              baseBarColor: searchbar2,
                              bufferedBarColor: searchbar2,
                              progressBarColor: textColors,
                              thumbColor: textColors,
                              barHeight: 4,
                              thumbRadius: 5,
                              timeLabelLocation: TimeLabelLocation.below,
                              timeLabelPadding: 3,
                              timeLabelType: TimeLabelType.remainingTime,
                              progress: positionData?.position ?? Duration.zero,
                              buffered: positionData?.bufferedPosition ??
                                  Duration.zero,
                              total: positionData?.duration ?? Duration.zero,
                              onSeek: _audioPlayer.seek,
                            );
                          }),
                      Controls(audioplayer: _audioPlayer),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ));
    }
  }
}
```